# I have a facebook developer account and have my APP_ID, APP_SECRET, Access Tokens, and checked my permissions. But running python code throws errror

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I have a Django application and have venv.  I have done the pip install of python-facebook-api==0.15.0 and facebook-sdk.

The code I was trying to run is

``
"""
This is an example for page get recent 50 feeds

```
Refer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#read
"""
```

```
import json
import os

from pyfacebook import GraphAPI

APP_ID = os.environ.get("APP_ID")  # Your App ID
APP_SECRET = os.environ.get("APP_SECRET")  # Your App secret
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ.get("ACCESS_TOKEN")  # Your Access Token
print('APP_ID = ', APP_ID)
print('APP_SECRET = ', APP_SECRET)
print('ACCESS_TOKEN = ', ACCESS_TOKEN)


def handler(page_id):
    api = GraphAPI(app_id=APP_ID, app_secret=APP_SECRET, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
    feed = api.get_full_connections(
        object_id=page_id,
        connection="feed",
        count=50,
        limit=25,
        fields="id,message,create_time",
    )
    with open(f"./{page_id}.json", "w+") as f:
        json.dump(feed, f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    handler(page_id="Prs7pf51tx4mfs")
`
```

`
This gives the following error message...

`

```
raise FacebookError(data)
pyfacebook.exceptions.FacebookError: FacebookError(code=100,message=Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'Prs7pf51tx4mfs' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api,type=GraphMethodException,error_subcode=33,fbtrace_id=AjeLHb_22QGbSeNRA8Hp_Nj)
```

I have Page Public Content Access ready to use and
pages_read_user_content ready for use.

I got the page_id from view page source after going to my profile page and searching for page_id.

I suspect the page_id is incorrect as it isn't a 15 digit number, but I could not find it and all the online help seems to be the classic UI or says to click something that doesn't exist in the new UI.

I am looking to get all the feeds on my page in a JSON I can parse.  I cannot even use the GraphAPI Explorer since the page_id is bad.

Thanks

Comment: _"I got the page_id from view page source after going to my profile page"_ - you should not be getting IDs from page source codes to begin with. What exactly do you mean by "my profile page" here? Are you talking about getting the posts from a user profile, or a page? Those are different things.

Comment: I tried both but I am most interested in the user home page.  I was unable find the page_id to use in the api

Comment: You can use `me` instead of an ID, that will automatically resolve to the ID of the user or page the token belongs to.

Comment: I tried 'me' instead of page_id in the above python code to access the Graph API but changing the object_id from page_id to 'me' gave me nothing.

Comment: Nothing? Or an error message again?